# How can android studio execute linux shell commands on windows?

Tags: java, linux, android-studio, cmd

I have issued something weird that I do not understand, I'm trying to launch cmd.exe from android studio but it's not working, this is my piece of code

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "n");
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
       Log.d("STATE",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

however, I tried putting shell commands like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

and it works! I don't know why, it executes linux commands like (pwd) and (ls), for pwd it gives (/n), but how is that possible? I'm using Android Studio on linux, can anybody help? thanks!